# Add a default text into Inline Ajax Comments WP plugin by jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, comments

I would like to add a default text in the comments of my wordpress site. The problem is that the plugin "[Inline Ajax Comments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-ajax-comments/)" don't then allows :

```
<textarea placeholder="Press enter to submit comment…" tabindex="4" id="comment" name="comment" class="inline-comments-auto-expand submit-on-enter"></textarea>
```

There is no problems without this plugin :

```
$(function () {
 $('#Change').bind("click", '#Change', Change);
 function Change() {$('#comment').text('My new text');};
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pJdY/1/

(I don't give you the plugin code, hoping that this is not a problem)

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

$('#comment').html('my new text');

That should work because to put  text within a textarea it needs to go between the tags. It's not like Assn input which uses an attribute (Val="").